# Why does tempered glass show black patterns under polarized light?

Tags: optics, polarization

[image: Glass pot lid]

I have placed a glass pot lid in-between a polarized white light source and a camera with a linear polarizer. The polarizers are offset by 90 degrees. I'm wondering why the squiggly lines that appear are black rather than colorful, like we normally see with stress birefringence:

[image: stress birefringence]

To my understanding, regular glass is isotropic so it should not display birefringence under cross polarization, but this lid is probably tempered glass which is why we see some patterns arise. What I am confused about is why there are no colors and only black patterns.